# Confidence intervals in java, testing the random pick of an element in a list of objects

Tags: java, random, confidence-interval, apache-commons-math

So I have this method that picks at random an object from a list of 2 objects. I would like to write a junit test (`@Test`) asserting based on a confidence level that somehow there's a 50% chance for each of the 2 objects to be picked.

The piece of code under test:

```
public MySepecialObj pickTheValue(List<MySepecialObj> objs, Random shufflingFactor) {

    // this could probably be done in a more efficient way
    // but my point is asserting on the 50% chance of the 
    // two objects inside the input list
    Collections.shuffle(objs, shufflingFactor);
    return objs.get(0);
}
```

In the test I would like to provide 2 mocks (`firstMySepecialObjMock` and `secondMySepecialObjMock`) as input objects of type `MySepecialObj` and `new Random()` as the input shuffling parameter, then assert that the `firstMySepecialObjMock` happens to be the choice 50% of the times and `secondMySepecialObjMock` happens to be the choice in the other 50% of the times.

Something like:

```
@Test
public void myTestShouldCheckTheConfidenceInterval() {

    // using Mockito here
    MySepecialObj firstMySepecialObjMock = mock(MySepecialObj.class);
    MySepecialObj secondMySepecialObjMock = mock(MySepecialObj.class);

    // using some helpers from Guava to build the input list
    List<MySepecialObj> theListOfTwoElements = Lists.newArrayList(firstMySepecialObjMock, secondMySepecialObjMock);

    // call the method (multiple times? how many?) like:
    MySepecialObj chosenValue = pickTheValue(theListOfTwoElements, new Random());

    // assert somehow on all the choices using a confidence level
    // verifying that firstMySepecialObjMock was picked ~50% of the times
    // and secondMySepecialObjMock was picked the other ~50% of the times
}
```

I am not sure about the statistics theory here, so maybe I should provide a different instance of `Random` with different parameters to its constructor?

I would also like to have a test where I could set the confidence level as a parameter (I guess usually is 95%, but it could be another value?).

- What could be a pure java solution/setup of the test involving a confidence level parameter?
- What could be an equivalent solution/setup of the test involving some helper library like the Apache Commons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all this is the normal way to pick random elements from a List in Java. (`nextInt(objs.size()` produces random integers between 0 and `objs.size()`).

   ```
   public MySepecialObj pickTheValue(List<MySepecialObj> objs, Random random) {
       int i = random.nextInt(objs.size());
       return objs.get(i);
   }
   ```
2. You can read [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checking_whether_a_coin_is_fair#Estimator_of_true_probability) about how many times you should perform an experiment with 2 possible outcomes for a given confidence level. E.g. for confidence level of 95% you get a confidence interval of 1.9599. You also need to provide a maximum error say 0.01. Then the number of times to perform the experiment:

   ```
   double confidenceInterval = 1.9599;
   double maxError = 0.01;
   int numberOfPicks = (int) (Math.pow(confidenceInterval, 2)/(4*Math.pow(maxError, 2)));
   ```

   which results in `numberOfPicks = 9603`. That's how many times you should call `pickTheValue`.
3. This would be how I recommend you perform the experiment multiple times (Note that `random` is being reused):

   ```
   Random random = new Random();
   double timesFirstWasPicked = 0;
   double timesSecondWasPicked = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPicks; ++i) {
       MySepecialObj chosenValue = pickTheValue(theListOfTwoElements, random);
       if (chosenValue == firstMySepecialObjMock) {
           ++timesFirstWasPicked;
       } else {
           ++timesSecondWasPicked;
       }
   }
   double probabilityFirst = timesFirstWasPicked / numberOfPicks;
   double probabilitySecond = timesSecondWasPicked / numberOfPicks;
   ```

   Then assert that `probabilityFirst`, `probabilitySecond` are no further than `maxError` from 0.5
4. I found a [BinomialTest](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math4/stat/inference/BinomialTest.html) class in apache-commons-math but I don't see how it can help in your case. It can calculate the confidence level from the number of experiments. You want the reverse of that.